# vertical align and valign not working on table!

Tags: html, css

I am dynamically generating a table using AJAX. The structure of the table to be populated is as follows:

```
<table id="foobar"  style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:20%;"></th>
            <th style="width:55%;"></th>
            <th title="widget name">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The cell data contains either:

- an image
- a div wrapper with anchor tags and paragraphs

I tried the following:

1. setting `valign="top"` (separately) at the `table`, `th` and `tr` levels - it had no effect
2. setting `style="vertical-align: top;"`  (separately) at the `table`, `th` and `tr` levels - it had no effect

I don't want to set the align property at the cell level because it will cause too much unnecessary bloat if the table contains several (say hundreds of) rows.

How can I force a table to vertically align its cell contents to top (bearing in mind that the cells contain block elements?

Comment: `valign` should work no matter what. Did you check your general CSS file what it defines for `TH` elements?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: you were right. my main CSS file had set td { vertical-align: bottom }. I fixed it thanks to your suggestion

Comment: Huh I suppose I should put it in an answer then and you'll be able to accept it. :) So I did. You can find my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`valign` should work no matter what if all settings that we see here are those that are actually used.

### Global CSS settings

But I suspect a different *gunman* here. Did you check your global CSS file what it defines for `TH` elements? Maybe that's what's giving you headaches.

Comment: It should be noted that valign is deprecated.

Comment: @wdm: use CSS then. But keep in mind that you may have some global CSS settings (that override `valign` just as well.

Comment: Especially if you are using a pre-fab template.  The one I was working on had a chunk of css at the top that set just about every tag to align to baseline.  I yanked that and everything popped into place.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a basic table example with TH and TD tags where the content is set to "vertical-align:top".

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HAQ3s/472/

```
th, td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>A<br /><br /></th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1<br /><br /></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not either `table th, table td` or `th, td`? I'd either limit both to inside a table, or none to inside a table. (Considering this specific situation, I'd just take `table` out.)

Comment: Yes they do. So why would you confuse the reader by using two distinct approaches in the same selector?

Answer (score 5):

To affect cells in the way you want, you do need to set the alignment at the cell level. Since you don't want to do this for each individual one, you need to think about adding a css/style section to your page. Here's a sample definition for what you need - this is normally in the head section or a separate file, but you could even have this just before the "< table" tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should edit the css to also include `th`s, which is what OP is fiddling with.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr {vertical-align: top;}
```

works for me with your example code, perhaps you need to see if a reset or something is explicitly setting the vertical alignment to middle or bottom on the `td`s

in that case something like

```
tr td {vertical-align: top;}
```

should also work to make the selector more specific, though in your actual use case it might need more depending on what is causing the `td` to overrule the `tr` setting

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had given `!important` so it was not worked. Once I removed that vertical alignment is working perfectly.

```
th, td {
    vertical-align: top; //Don't use !important keyword.
}
```

Hope it helps for someone.